# How to count all matched times with awk?

Tags: awk

```
echo '#  x y z w  '| awk '/\w/{++cnt} END {print "Count = ", cnt}' 
1
```

How to output 4 as result?
 x and y and z and w ,four of them matched the pattern  **\w**.
For the string here `#  x y z w`,all matched times is 4.

Comment: `awk` works by default on lines as records, you want to iterate over all fields or set RS to white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for what you're trying to do either iterate over all fields and count, or change RS so that `awk` will do it for you

```
echo '#  x y z w  ' | awk -v RS=' +' '/\w/{++cnt} END {print "Count = ", cnt}'
```

However, a better method, which will work line by line for multi-line input can be

```
echo '#  x y z w  ' | awk '{print "Count:", gsub(/\w/,"&")}'
```

both might be `GNU` specific and your `awk` may not support, so

```
... | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/\w/) cnt++} END{print ...'
```

Comment: All those solutions are GNU specific courtesy of `\w`. Change `\w` to a POSIX bracket expression and then only the first one would still be gawk-specific due to multi-char RS.

Comment: echo '#  x y z w  ' | awk '{print "Count:", gsub(/\w+/,"&")}'